# In the first episode of Stargate: SG-1, did the rock-throwing guy actually help?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

For reasons intelligible only to me, the prisoner who stays and helps O'Neil by throwing rocks as his people escape sticks out to me.

Is there anything that he did that was actually useful? For instance, did he hit anyone with a rock? Did his rocks disrupt the attackers in any other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [original script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/stargate-sg-1-101-children-of-the-gods-1997.pdf), the 'primitive' is extremely effective. He disables a serpent guard all on his own.

> KAWALSKY, WARREN AND CASEY are firing on automatic now, there are so many targets around them. And it takes hundreds of our conventional bullets to penetrate the serpent guard's armor.
>
> POV O'NEILL  - They are surrounded now. and the noose is tightening. He SEES the PRIMITIVE throwing huge chunks of rubble from the crumbling temple, itching to join the battle. O'Neill breaks an M-16 out and hands it to the Primitive.
>
> **O'NEILL**: *Here! Use this!*
>
> O'Neill points in the direction of the Serpent Guards, but the Primitive throws the rifle like a javelin instead! It soars fifty yards through the air. A SERPENT GUARD is struck down by the flying weapon...
>
> O'NEILL pats the Primitive on the arm.

He's also the one that grabs (and kills) a Jaffa that was approaching the gate, unfortunately unleashing the Goa'uld symbiote that was being carried.